# I Installed windows on a new ssd and I lost Ubuntu on another hhd

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

Now, the only working operating system is Windows 10. When I go to my Pc in windows, I don't even see my hhd. Is there anyway to save this mess? I tried to unplug my ssd and see if ubuntu shows but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You probaly go two problems here, the first one is:

> the only working operating system is Windows 10.

You probably just replace the default boot drive with the drive where Windows is installed, in this case, you will need to change the boot order, and place the HHD where ubuntu is installed as the first option on the boot order list, ([this guide](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-boot-order-in-bios-2624528) can give you some idea of how to do it. ) after this you will probably see the grub system selector page when your PC starts.

Now to the second problem:

> When I go to my Pc in windows, I don't even see my hhd.

The reason that Ubuntu drive doesn't show up is that Windows and Ubuntu use different types of file system technology. Windows uses NFTS and Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, etc) uses EXT4, Windows doesn't support EXT4. To see the Ubuntu drive on Windows, you will need to divide the Ubuntu drive into two partitions, one EXT4 for Ubuntu and another one in NFTS.